# what does ''it'' refer to in a sentence?

Tags: dummy-pronouns

> If I see an article advertised, **it** is the surest proof I know that the article does what is claimed for it, and that it is good value.

What does the word "**it**" refer to? Is the word "**it**" a "*dummy subject*"?

Comment: "It" is a dummy pronoun referring to the preceding noun phrase "an article advertised". We understand that the advertising of an article is the surest proof ...

Comment: "**it is the surest proof**" can be likewise rephrased to "**that is the surest proof**"